# Deserialize JSON to polymorphic types Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am working on an e-policy project where i need to save different types of policies. For simplicity i am considering only two types "LifeInsurance" and "AutoInsurance". What i want to achieve is if the JSON request to create policy contains "type":"AUTO_INSURANCE" then the request should be mapped to AutoInsurance.class likewise for LifeInsurance but currently in spring boot app the request is getting mapped to parent class Policy eliminating the specific request fields for auto/Life insurance. The domain model i have created is as below.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = AutoInsurance.class, name = "AUTO_INSURANCE"),
    @Type(value = LifeInsurance.class) })
public class Policy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String policyNumber;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PolicyType policyType;
    private String name;

}
```

My AutoInsurance class is below.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonTypeName(value = "AUTO_INSURANCE")
public class AutoInsurance extends Policy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String vehicleNumber;
    private String model;
    private String vehicleType;
    private String vehicleName;

}
```

Below is LifeInsurance type child class

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeName(value = "LIFE_INSURANCE")
public class LifeInsurance extends Policy {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "policy")
    private List<Dependents> dependents;
    private String medicalIssues;
    private String medication;
    private String treatments;

}
```

To save the policy details, I am sending  JSON request from UI with a "type" property indicating the type of insurance in the request.

When i run the below test method, JSON request gets mapped to the correct child class as required.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {
        ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
        String s = "{\"id\": 1,\"policyNumber\": \"Aut-123\",\"type\": \"AUTO_INSURANCE\",\"policyType\": \"AUTO_INSURANCE\",\"name\": null,\"address\": null,\"contact\": null,\"agentNumber\": null,\"agentName\": null,\"issuedOn\": null,\"startDate\": null,\"endDate\": null,\"vehicleNumber\": \"HR\",\"model\": null,\"vehicleType\": \"SUV\",\"vehicleName\": null}";
        Policy p = map.readValue(s, Policy.class);
        System.out.println(p.getClass());
        //SpringApplication.run(EPolicyApplication.class, args);
    }
```

But when i run the same in Spring boot in a RESTController postmapping, I am getting a PArent class object instead of the child class object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/policy")
public class PolicyController {

    @PostMapping
    public void savePolicy(Policy policy) {
        System.out.println(policy.getClass());
    }
}
```

I can get the JSON as string, autowire objectmapper and parse manually but i want to understand if its a known issue and if anyone else has faced the same with Spring boot. I have searched for solutions on this but i got was solution to deserializing to polymorphic classes but nothing related to issue with Spring boot.

Comment: You are missing the `@RequestBody` annoation on the request object, so nothing will be deserialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). This resolved the issue. I was just checking the class name but didn't validate the data if that's getting mapped or not. After adding it worked

Comment: You can add this as the answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method you haven't annotated the `Policy` method argument with `@RequestBody`. Which leads to Spring creating just an instance of `Policy` instead of using Jackson to convert the request body.

```
@PostMapping
public void savePolicy(@RequestBody Policy policy) {
    System.out.println(policy.getClass());
}
```

Adding the `@RequestBody` will make that Spring uses Jackson to deserialize the request body and with that your annotations/configuration will be effective.